# Unexpected removal of relationship using SDN4

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a test in my data model failing that previously passed after converting some neo4j-ogm code to use spring-data. However, I'm almost sure spring-data-neo4j is not the cause of the issue I am having. More something conceptually I'm missing (about sessions or dirtiness or something?)

The behavior of the test is:

```
Save Object A
Save Object B with relationship to A
Set property of Object A
Save Object A
```

Previously, Node A was updated with its property and there was a relationship existing between Node A and Node B in the database after test execution.

After the conversion however, the result is the same except that the relationship between Node A and Node B no longer exists in the database (it is removed) after Object A is saved the second time.

Could there be anything I've done to change this behaviour? What is expected behaviour?

Comment: Are all these operations happening within the same session? Does object A have a reference to object B as well when you save B with a relationship to A?

Comment: Yes they were happening within the same session. Object A did not have a reference to B but this was fine previously with ogm. To fix the problem in spring data I had to create a reference from A to B. I guess this is what you expect? :)

Comment: Yes, it is, but it should behave exactly the same with the ogm. What is the session scope? All these operations in the same method?